# Can't Start IPMIView on Windows 7 or 10

Tags: windows, ipmi

I have downloaded and installed SuperMicro IPMIView 2.16.0 on 4 machines, 2 each on both Windows 7 and 10.  When I start the program from the start menu, the hourglass spins for a few seconds and then nothing happens.  There are to entries in any event logs.  I have googled and not even found anyone having this problem. I see many others having problems getting a remote console to work, but I can't even start the program!  I can't figure out why I am a special case.

It seems to work fine on CentOS 7.

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

windows 10
Find SUPERMICRO and expand themenu
right click on IPMIView in the menu.
Then select More.
Then select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Thanks!  That is of course the solution and became obvious to me right after I read my own post.  Sometimes I amaze myself with I can miss the obvious!